# "length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent" on one of two very similar sets

Tags: r

I collected data in two data frames `vols` and `flow`. The latter can be converted to matrix but the first not:

```
as.matrix(vols)
Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c("CanovesSamalus", "Llinars",  : 
  length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent
```

What is amiss?

```
> vols[1:3,]
    data CanovesSamalus Llinars LlinarsCanoves Mirador Santacana StAntoniVilamajor   N1    N3   N4   N7   N9
1 2011-01-01             NA  172.66       3779.832 453.096  4996.344           1830.09 9898 9898 9898 9898 9898
2 2011-01-02             NA  172.66       3809.036 494.977  4699.088           1712.43 9898 9898 9898 9898 9898
3 2011-01-03             NA  172.66       3134.215 517.979  4319.374           1716.67 9898 9898 9898 9898 9898

> str(vols)
List of 12
 $ data             : Date[1:365], format: "2011-01-01" "2011-01-02" "2011-01-03" "2011-01-04" ...
 $ CanovesSamalus   : num [1:365] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Llinars          : num [1:365] 173 173 173 172 172 ...
 $ LlinarsCanoves   : num [1:365] 3780 3809 3134 3221 3113 ...
 $ Mirador          : num [1:365] 453 495 518 516 495 ...
 $ Santacana        : num [1:365] 4996 4699 4319 4276 4179 ...
 $ StAntoniVilamajor: num [1:365] 1830 1712 1717 1671 1733 ...
 $ N1               : num [1:365] 9898 9898 9898 9898 9898 ...
 $ N3               : num [1:365] 9898 9898 9898 9898 9898 ...
 $ N4               : num [1:365] 9898 9898 9898 9898 9898 ...
 $ N7               : num [1:365] 9898 9898 9898 9898 9898 ...
 $ N9               : num [1:365] 9898 9898 9898 9898 9898 ...
 - attr(*, "row.names")= int [1:365] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 - attr(*, "idvars")= chr "data"
 - attr(*, "rdimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ :'data.frame':    365 obs. of  1 variable:
  .. ..$ data: Date[1:365], format: "2011-01-01" "2011-01-02" "2011-01-03" "2011-01-04" ...
  ..$ :'data.frame':    6 obs. of  1 variable:
  .. ..$ node: Factor w/ 6 levels "CanovesSamalus",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

and:

```
> flow[1:3,]
    data N8FT01001 N9FT00201 N9FT00401 N9FT00402 N9FT00403 N9FT00801 N9FT01001 N9FT01002 N9FT01101 N9FT01201 N9FT01202
1 2011-01-01      7123         0      2113      3105       172       791      3909      2489      1188      1182      1135
2 2011-01-02      4197         0      1984      1887       152       801      2255      2449      1227      1221      1090
3 2011-01-03      3685         0      2221      1664        27       769      1969      2516      1512      1509      1400
N9FT01301 N9FT01401
1       118       119
2       114       115
3        77        78


> str(flow)
List of 14
 $ data     : Date[1:365], format: "2011-01-01" "2011-01-02" "2011-01-03" "2011-01-04" ...
 $ N8FT01001: int [1:365] 7123 4197 3685 4616 4534 6024 3118 5977 5455 2845 ...
 $ N9FT00201: int [1:365] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ N9FT00401: int [1:365] 2113 1984 2221 2010 1994 1776 2049 1953 2068 2028 ...
 $ N9FT00402: int [1:365] 3105 1887 1664 2066 2004 2741 1395 2645 2563 1064 ...
 $ N9FT00403: int [1:365] 172 152 27 4 14 180 14 166 155 5 ...
 $ N9FT00801: int [1:365] 791 801 769 789 688 663 730 732 767 694 ...
 $ N9FT01001: int [1:365] 3909 2255 1969 2487 2467 3198 1681 3249 2812 1740 ...
 $ N9FT01002: int [1:365] 2489 2449 2516 2551 2582 2476 2513 2582 2584 2602 ...
 $ N9FT01101: int [1:365] 1188 1227 1512 1236 1317 1006 1449 1171 1327 1345 ...
 $ N9FT01201: int [1:365] 1182 1221 1509 1232 1313 1002 1445 1167 1321 1341 ...
 $ N9FT01202: int [1:365] 1135 1090 1400 1112 1236 922 1283 1048 1218 1137 ...
 $ N9FT01301: int [1:365] 118 114 77 92 102 102 137 115 133 174 ...
 $ N9FT01401: int [1:365] 119 115 78 93 103 103 138 116 134 175 ...
 - attr(*, "row.names")= int [1:365] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 - attr(*, "idvars")= chr "data"
 - attr(*, "rdimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ :'data.frame':    365 obs. of  1 variable:
  .. ..$ data: Date[1:365], format: "2011-01-01" "2011-01-02" "2011-01-03" "2011-01-04" ...
  ..$ :'data.frame':    13 obs. of  1 variable:
  .. ..$ TAG: Factor w/ 13 levels "N8FT01001","N9FT00201",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
```

Comment: What  do you get if you try `as.matrix(vols[,-1])`! but it is really odd! that should works!

Comment: It works well

<pre>
       [,1]    [,2]     [,3]    [,4]     [,5]    [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11]
       [1,]   NA 172.660 3779.832 453.096 4996.344 1830.09 9898 9898 9898  9898  9898
</pre>

Comment: How did you create those data.frames? The `str` output does not look as I would expect for an ordinary data.frame. Try `as.matrix(as.data.frame(vols))`.

Comment: `as.matrix(as.data.frame(vols))` works. Thanks.

Comment: Both come from Excel sheets by `read.xls`, date formatted in `data` using `as.date` with `"%m-%d-%y"`. `flow` is `cast` (without previous `melt`) and row-ordered by `flow$data` .
Similarly for `vols`, except that this one is `melt` and `merge`d with another table to compute a new column that is added to it before being `cast`.

Comment: And `all(vols$data == flow$data)` gives `TRUE`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is unclear how you created those data.frames. From the `str` output they appear not to be ordinary data.frames but some other kind of lists, so it might be necessary to convert your objects to data.frames first. Use `as.matrix(as.data.frame(vols))`.

Comment: Done but now all is converted to chars:`as.matrix(as.data.frame(vols))[1,]`
gives
     `data    CanovesSamalus           Llinars    LlinarsCanoves           Mirador         Santacana StAntoniVilamajor                N1                N3 <newline>
     "2011-01-01"                NA         "172.660"        "3779.832"   `...

Comment: A matrix can only contain one data type. You could convert your dates to numerics.

Comment: That seeems to do it. Thanks!