# predict R with SVM

Tags: r, predict

I am trying to predict on R some data using svm to create the model and predict

below I attaced some code I hope explain myself

```
datos<-read.csv("Seguros.csv",sep = ";",dec='.',header=T)
muestra<-sample(nrow(datos),4400)
aprendizaje<-datos[muestra,]
datosPrec <- read.csv("SegurosNuevosVE150.csv", sep = ";", dec = ".", header = T)
modeloSig <- svm(Fraude ~ ., data = aprendizaje, kernel = "sigmoid")
modeloSig
predictFinal <- predict(modeloSig, datosPrec[, 16])
```

and I get this error

Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c("MontoPagado", "Interes", "Plazo",  : 
  length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent

The data on both is the same the only difference is the amount of rows and that the last colummn call "Fraude" instead of saying "Si" o "No" it says "NA" on SegurosNuevosVE150.csv below I attached the summary, I hoped I explained myself

summary (Seguros.csv)

MontoPagado          Interes            Plazo                  Tipo       Mensualidad
 Min.   :   -3453   Min.   :-0.6448   Min.   : 64.0   Internacional: 343   Min.   :  5003
 1st Qu.: 2284315   1st Qu.:17.0000   1st Qu.:404.0   Nacional     :6070   1st Qu.: 12164
 Median : 3831087   Median :17.2500   Median :444.3                        Median : 17299
 Mean   : 4585558   Mean   :15.8877   Mean   :438.4                        Mean   : 23496
 3rd Qu.: 5792869   3rd Qu.:17.7500   3rd Qu.:478.7                        3rd Qu.: 28939
 Max.   :49019276   Max.   :18.7500   Max.   :515.3                        Max.   :276296

MontoAsegurado    TipoPago       ModoPago    Fiador    Fiador2   OtroSeguro     Record
 Min.   :   7803   A:4158   Cajas     : 607   No:3278   No:5527   No:5310    R0     :5310
 1st Qu.: 401439   B:1817   NoDefinido: 450   Si:3135   Si: 886   Si:1103    R2     : 530
 Median : 613561   C: 438   Tarjeta   :5356                                  R1     : 495
 Mean   : 764561                                                             R5     :  40
 3rd Qu.: 916591                                                             R6     :  26
 Max.   :7734773                                                             R7     :   5
                                                                             (Other):   7
      Edad           EstadoCivil      Salario       Fraude
 Min.   :21.00   Divorciado: 229   Min.   :     0   No:6146
 1st Qu.:33.50   NoAplica  :  25   1st Qu.:     0   Si: 267
 Median :35.50   Soltero   :5895   Median :     0
 Mean   :36.58   Union     : 256   Mean   :  4126
 3rd Qu.:38.50   Viudo     :   8   3rd Qu.:  6404
 Max.   :57.00                     Max.   :104185

summary(SegurosNuevosVE150.csv)

MontoPagado          Interes          Plazo                  Tipo      Mensualidad     MontoAsegurado
 Min.   :     613   Min.   :-0.50   Min.   :302.7   Internacional:  6   Min.   :  5029   Min.   :   8470
 1st Qu.: 2678695   1st Qu.:17.25   1st Qu.:431.3   Nacional     :144   1st Qu.: 12122   1st Qu.: 462045
 Median : 3987711   Median :17.25   Median :434.0                       Median : 17533   Median : 639318
 Mean   : 4915943   Mean   :16.40   Mean   :439.9                       Mean   : 24432   Mean   : 806379
 3rd Qu.: 6780419   3rd Qu.:17.62   3rd Qu.:474.7                       3rd Qu.: 29269   3rd Qu.:1091095
 Max.   :28647806   Max.   :17.75   Max.   :492.7                       Max.   :148886   Max.   :4552955
 TipoPago       ModoPago  Fiador  Fiador2  OtroSeguro Record        Edad           EstadoCivil 
 A:100    Cajas     : 9   No:82   No:127   No:130     R0:130   Min.   :31.00   Divorciado:  5
 B: 36    NoDefinido:44   Si:68   Si: 23   Si: 20     R1:  9   1st Qu.:33.50   Soltero   :140
 C: 14    Tarjeta   :97                               R2: 11   Median :35.50   Union     :  4
                                                               Mean   :36.78   Viudo     :  1
                                                               3rd Qu.:39.00
                                                               Max.   :57.00
    Salario       Fraude
 Min.   :    0   Mode:logical
 1st Qu.:    0   NA's:150
 Median : 3806
 Mean   : 5198
 3rd Qu.: 7432
 Max.   :82010

Comment: Maybe you should try this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15084803/length-of-dimnames-2-not-equal-to-array-extent-on-one-of-two-very-similar

Comment: Thanks @andresram1 I tried that but didn't work, I am trying to do a prediction with the data and using what is recommend will conver everything to char which it doesn't work to predict, I think the problem here is that the SegurosNuevosVE150.csv has the Column "Fraude" as logical with all rows on NA and the first has this column in Factors with 2 levels "Si" o "No", but I need to change the NA on SegurosNuevosVE150.csv to "Si" o "No" beause that is what I am predicting

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is simply in your last line. The argument you pass for 'newdata' only specifies 1 column of your dataframe when you need to specify the entirety of it.

```
modeloSig <- svm(Fraude ~ ., data = aprendizaje, kernel = "sigmoid")
predictFinal <- predict(modeloSig, newdata=datosPrec) #changed datosPrec
```

Comment: Thanks @Jason that seems to do something different, but didn't worked now I get this error 
Error in newdata[, object$scaled, drop = FALSE] : 
  (subscript) logical subscript too long

Comment: That probably means that one of the categorical variables in your `newdata` dataset isn't present in the training dataset. You need to make sure they are in the same format

Comment: that is the problem in training the column "Fraude" is a factor with 2 levels while the other one this column "Fraude" is full of NA but it is the variable that I need to predict to

Comment: That's not the problem. The issue is that one of the variables which you used in your model (not the dependent variable) has more levels in the new dataset than in the training one. Can you run `str(data)` for both datasets? I'm betting you are going to be able to see it right off.